# Java "illegal start of expression" error...........How to fix this error?

Tags: java, expression

I was developing a program using NetBeans IDE and i got an error in front of a line saying

> illegal start of expression and below that written ';' expected

I am new to Java and I am unable to fix this error when I was assigning a value to an array.

Below is a part of code where the error occured :

---

```
String[] colname;
   int j=0;
   while(rs.next()){
     for(int i=0;i<cols;i++){
       colname={dtm.getColumnName(i)};       //**<-- This is where the error occured**
                }
                    colName=colname;   //colName is also an array of String datatype.
                    Object[] value = {rs.getObject(colName[j])};
                    dtm.addRow(value);
                    j++;
                }
```

---

All apart the line

```
colname={dtm.getColumnName(i)};
```

Does not give any error. But the error occurs only in the above line.

I found myself unable to fix it. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 ways of initializing an array:

```
String[] colname= {dtm.getColumnName(i)};
```

or

```
colname= new String[] {dtm.getColumnName(i)};
```

But you can't mix them. In your case, you would use the latter because you don't have the information to populate it yet on the line where you declare it.

Note however that this is probably not going to do what you want as you will keep reassigning a new array at each loop. You could make your life easier by using an ArrayList instead:

```
List<String> colName = new ArrayList<String> ();

//in your loop
colName.add(dtm.getColumnName(i));
```

You can read more about arrays in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Thanxx it helped to resolve my problem and it fixed the error!

Comment: well i don't know about ArrayList at this time but will soon get to know

But your former solution of giving `new String[]` solved the problem..

thanxx again

Comment: Sorry I got it now why you were telling me about using the ArrayList but there's again an error

The declaration `List<String> colName=new ArrayList<String> ();` is giving the following error : \n

"type List does not take parameters" 

So can you please tell me what to do now??

I'm using the `ArrayList` first time may be that's why I don't know how to use it and it's giving an error

Comment: You should post a new question with the relevant details: code that does not compile + imports.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use that form of array creation when simply assigning to a variable - it's only valid as part of a variable declaration. You need:

```
colname = new String[] { dtm.getColumnName(i) };
```

However, I don't think this *actually* does what you want it to... all but the last iteration of the loop will be pointless.

You probably want something more like:

```
String[] colNames = new String[cols];
for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    colNames[i] = dtm.getColumnName(i);
}
```

I would also *strongly* recommend that you avoid code like this:

```
 colName=colname;
```

Having two variables which differ only in case is a *really* bad idea.

Comment: the above solution of assigning an array solved the problem 

well i just tried to fix the error by doing colName=colname; but it didn't helped

the actual code to be written was 

`colname=new String[] {dtm.getColumnName(i)};`

and it solved the problem.

Thanxx

Comment: @ShivamArora: Don't assume that just because you've now got it to compile, that it's *correct*. The code you've presented is pretty odd - you should look at the whole thing again, IMO.

Comment: thanxx......I will look up on the whole thing.

At this time I'm just creating a method.. the actual result will come later when I will design the forms.

Can i take your help in case a runtime error occurs??

Comment: @ShivamArora: Well, you can post another question on Stack Overflow. I would *strongly* advise you to test your code as you go though, ideally with unit tests. Leaving everything until you've got a UI is a recipe for integration nightmares.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans IDE and i think it automatically tells about the compile-time errors. 
And after going with your solution there's not any compile-time error in the code.

If any runtime error occured after I designed the frames,I will put another question on Stack Overflow askign for help.